# To include something in your daily routine/plans/schedule/timetable

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, idioms

Let's imagine someone is giving some pieces of advice to a person who is looking for some hobbies for their leisure time. 
He says:

> - Have you ever read about the benefits of reading books?! Did you know that reading always can keep your brain young? It has lots of advantages. It can melt away your stress. So, I'd highly recommend you to include it in your daily.............

a. plans 
b. schedule 
c. timetable 
d. routine

I wonder what word is normally used in this sense? Actually, I have encountered all the listed choices above, but I have no idea which one is used when in this specific case. Also, I'm not quite sure whether the writer of the passages which I faced those structures had been natives or just they had been some translated excerpts of a bigger contexts. 
Please note that I am looking for a fixed idiom. 
Thank you.
To me, "a" works the best, but I have seen the "b" construction too and as far as I'm concerned, "schedule" and "timetable" are almost always interchangeable. The choice "d" was observed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add (e) habit and (f) regimen. The slightly-different phrasings do carry slightly-different connotations. I can't say one is correct for ALL situations. For example, for those who have explicit daily plans, (a) makes sense, but it does not make sense for someone who never has daily plans.

Since we're specifically addressing leisure time, which is not necessarily on a daily cycle, you might say "consider adding reading to your list of leisure activities" or "consider picking a book that you can read when you're at leisure."

Comment: Thank you @Edward Barnard. And then I wonder what would be your pick(s) out of them all and why? Additionally, I know that "habit" is a countable/uncountable noun. So can I say: "include it in your daily habit**s**"? If no, then please kindly enlighten me why?

Comment: Yes, "include it in your daily habits" is correct. Since I read a LOT, I don't think of adding it to my schedule... I think of reading as a habit.